# Python sqlalchemy core Inspector.get_columns AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'contextual_connect'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use metadata and inspect with its methods to get the column name of datatable stored in redshift.

As long as I call `get_columns` it would raise an AttributeError

**My code**

```
metadata = MetaData()
inspect_engine = inspect(engine)
inspect_engine.get_schema_names() # This returns a list of schema
inspect_engine.get_table_names(schema="my_schema") # This returns a list of table names
inspect_engine.get_columns(schema="my_schema", table_name="my_table") # This raise an AttributeError

AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'contextual_connect'
```

**Summary**

1. `inspect_engine.get_schema_names()` and `inspect_engine.get_table_names(schema="my_schema")` works
2. `inspect_engine.get_columns(schema="my_schema", table_name="my_table")` not working
3. I saw `my_schema` in the list which returns by `inspect_engine.get_schema_names()`; `my_table` in the list which returns by `inspect_engine.get_table_names(schema="my_schema")`
4. Version: sqlalchemy 1.4.7

**Question**

If it is the problem of connection why `get_schema_names` and `get_table_names` works?

How to makes `get_columns` works in this case ?

Comment: `table_name` is a positional argument. `insp.get_columns("team", schema_name="dbo")` works for me.

Comment: @GordThompson, changed the table name to positional arg, `inspect_engine.get_columns("table_name", schema="schema")` but got still the same error

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/FpWePUc6) works for me with plain PostgreSQL/psycopg2. If it doesn't work with sqlalchemy-redshift then it might be related to their GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift/issues/214).